# haxe get type info for fields of a function type parameter

Tags: haxe, type-parameter

`Reflect` can list an object's fields at runtime, but doesn't have type info. rtti has type info, but doesn't seem to work for type parameters.

In this example, I want `MyLibrary` to be able to figure out that `T`'s `val` field is an `Int`.

```
import haxe.Constraints;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        var obj :IntStruct = MyLibrary.foo();
    }
}

@:rtti
class IntStruct {
    public var val :Int;
    public function new() { }
}

class MyLibrary {
    @:generic
    public static function foo<T:Constructible<()->Void>>() :T {
        var something = new T();
        trace(Reflect.fields(something));   // [val]
        trace(haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(T));   // fails here
        return something;
    }
}
```

this gives this compile error:

```
Main.hx:20: characters 38-39 : Only @:const type parameters on @:generic classes can be used as value
```

if I add `@:const` to the type parameter declaration, I get this instead

```
Main.hx:20: characters 38-39 : foo.T should be Class<Unknown<0>>
Main.hx:20: characters 38-39 : ... For function argument 'c'
```

Since `foo` is generic, the compiler will write a separate function for each `T`, so it should be no problem for it to tell me about `T` inside `foo`. How can it be done?

Comment: `T` doesn't exist at runtime (though I agree, with @:generic, it should be constant... you can new it.) But you have an instance of it, so does it accomplish what you want to do: `trace(haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(Type.getClass(something)));`

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I wanted, thanks. It's so obvious now that I see it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.